# How can i add net5.0 Worker Application AddJsonOptions

Tags: c#, json, .net, .net-core, worker

There are API project and Worker project in the solution. The API project is written in net5.0 Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.
In Startup.cs

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()); // for enum as strings
            });
```

This code block is available in Startup.cs.

I also want to add these JsonOptions to net5.0 Worker project but **Controller and Startup.cs are not available** in worker project. How can i add?

I tried this

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    });
```

and this

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(o =>
{
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = null;
});
```

but not works for me

Comment: `AddJsonOptions` are only used to bind/send json via endpoints, worker project does not expose any endpoints (at least by default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AddJsonOptions` are only used to bind/send json via endpoints, worker project does not expose any endpoints (at least by default), so there is no point adding them unless you resolve `IOptions<JsonOptions>` somewhere in the code directly. In this case you can always call `Configure`:

```cs
services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()); // for enum as strings
});
```